# WebdriverIO: Unable to use .getAlertText() method "Unresolved function or method getAlertText()"

Tags: javascript, selenium, npm, webstorm, webdriver-io

I am using WebStorm to write some automated tests.  For one test, I must check if an alert prompts the user.  To accomplish this, I want to use the `.getAlertText();` method, however WebStorm does not recognize the method.  It says "Unresolved function or method getAlertText()".

The WebdriverIO documentation shows that it is indeed a method: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html

How can I get WebStorm to allow me to use the method?  Thank you.

Comment: Post your [MCVE], what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this method is missing in [wdio typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webdriverio/index.d.ts), that's why the IDE can't resolve it during static code analysis.
I believe that this has to be submitted to either https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues or https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues

Comment: Thank you!  Does this mean that the method cannot be used, despite it being shown in the documentation?  How about the method `.alertText()`?  I am also having issues with this method as well.

Comment: no, it doesn't. It just means that the typings have to be updated to match the actual docs

Answer (score 0):

Reference:
http://v4.webdriver.io/api/protocol/alertText.html

v4 have function alertText(); && v5 have getAlertText()